# Upgrade my SharePoint 2010 database from 2008 SP1 to 2008R2 SP3

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have SharePoint 2010 running on SQL Server 2008 SP1. I would like to upgrade the database to 2008R2 SP3.

Are there any problems with that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upgrade the SQL server but you have to plan it, as it will cause the outage for SharePoint. following things

- You must have full backup of your content databases before start. so that in case of corruption you have a recovery point.
- Highly recommend,test this upgrade in lower farm
- Shut down SharePoint while you upgrading the SQL so that no active connection from SharePoint to avoid any corruption.Personally i am in favor of shutting down servers but people just stop the IIS, SharePoint timer and other services.
- Schedule this activity, as it will cause the outage for SharePoint user.